# three.js add button on object for showing info about that location

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, 3d

I have an object loaded with GLTF loader into my scene:

```
        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load( 'files/3.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

            gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
```

I need to create a point on this object to show popup info.

How can I add a point to a specification location on the object?

Answer (score 2):

You can add invisible cube/sphere using online three.js editor https://threejs.org/editor/, place it where you want, add userdata to this object for example raycast: true, export to gltf, then add element to an array of raycastable elements

```
gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
    if(child.userData.raycast) raycastable.push(child);
})
```

Then check for intersection in render loop
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for this. 
1. You can add Button through software from which you get that object.
2. You can create separate custom Button/Object in THREE.js itself and place it on scene with GLTF object.

Thanks